# Trying to iterate through a list looking for specific dictionary key

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull out from JSON a list of items from transactions. I know what the key is I am looking for but need to iterate through the list looking for the key and then pull out specific info from there. Sample of the raw JSON is:

```
    {
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 645,
      "order_number": 645,
      "created_at": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
      "completed_at": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
      "status": "processing",
      "currency": "USD",
      "total": "79.87",
      "subtotal": "63.97",
      "total_line_items_quantity": 3,
      "total_tax": "5.90",
      "total_shipping": "10.00",
      "cart_tax": "5.40",
      "shipping_tax": "0.50",
      "total_discount": "0.00",
      "shipping_methods": "Flat Rate",
      "payment_details": {
        "method_id": "bacs",
        "method_title": "Direct Bank Transfer",
        "paid": true
      },
      "billing_address": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
      },
      "shipping_address": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US"
      },
      "note": "",
      "customer_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "customer_user_agent": "WordPress/4.1; http://example.com",
      "customer_id": 2,
      "view_order_url": "https://example.com/my-account/view-order/645",
      "line_items": [
        {
          "id": 504,
          "subtotal": "43.98",
          "subtotal_tax": "4.40",
          "total": "43.98",
          "total_tax": "4.40",
          "price": "21.99",
          "quantity": 2,
          "tax_class": "reduced-rate",
          "name": "Premium Quality",
          "product_id": 546,
          "sku": "",
          "meta": []
        },
        {
          "id": 505,
          "subtotal": "19.99",
          "subtotal_tax": "1.00",
          "total": "19.99",
          "total_tax": "1.00",
          "price": "19.99",
          "quantity": 1,
          "tax_class": null,
          "name": "Ship Your Idea",
          "product_id": 613,
          "sku": "",
          "meta": [
            {
              "key": "pa_color",
              "label": "Color",
              "value": "Black"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "shipping_lines": [
        {
          "id": 506,
          "method_id": "flat_rate",
          "method_title": "Flat Rate",
          "total": "10.00"
        }
      ],
      "tax_lines": [
        {
          "id": 507,
          "rate_id": "5",
          "code": "US-CA-TAX-1",
          "title": "Tax",
          "total": "4.40",
          "compound": false
        },
        {
          "id": 508,
          "rate_id": "4",
          "code": "US-STANDARD-1",
          "title": "Standard",
          "total": "1.50",
          "compound": false
        }
      ],
      "fee_lines": [],
      "coupon_lines": [],
      "customer": {
        "id": 2,
        "created_at": "2014-11-19T18:34:19Z",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "username": "john.doe",
        "last_order_id": "645",
        "last_order_date": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
        "orders_count": 2,
        "total_spent": "19.00",
        "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=96",
        "billing_address": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "company": "",
          "address_1": "969 Market",
          "address_2": "",
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "state": "CA",
          "postcode": "94103",
          "country": "US",
          "email": "john.doe@example.com",
          "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
        },
        "shipping_address": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "company": "",
          "address_1": "969 Market",
          "address_2": "",
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "state": "CA",
          "postcode": "94103",
          "country": "US"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 644,
      "order_number": 644,
      "created_at": "2015-01-26T19:33:42Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-01-26T19:33:42Z",
      "completed_at": "2015-01-26T19:33:42Z",
      "status": "on-hold",
      "currency": "USD",
      "total": "44.14",
      "subtotal": "30.99",
      "total_line_items_quantity": 2,
      "total_tax": "3.15",
      "total_shipping": "10.00",
      "cart_tax": "2.65",
      "shipping_tax": "0.50",
      "total_discount": "0.00",
      "shipping_methods": "Flat Rate",
      "payment_details": {
        "method_id": "bacs",
        "method_title": "Direct Bank Transfer",
        "paid": false
      },
      "billing_address": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
      },
      "shipping_address": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US"
      },
      "note": "",
      "customer_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "customer_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36",
      "customer_id": 2,
      "view_order_url": "https://example.com/my-account/view-order/644",
      "line_items": [
        {
          "id": 499,
          "subtotal": "21.99",
          "subtotal_tax": "2.20",
          "total": "21.99",
          "total_tax": "2.20",
          "price": "21.99",
          "quantity": 1,
          "tax_class": "reduced-rate",
          "name": "Premium Quality",
          "product_id": 546,
          "sku": "",
          "meta": []
        },
        {
          "id": 500,
          "subtotal": "9.00",
          "subtotal_tax": "0.45",
          "total": "9.00",
          "total_tax": "0.45",
          "price": "9.00",
          "quantity": 1,
          "tax_class": null,
          "name": "Woo Album #4",
          "product_id": 96,
          "sku": "",
          "meta": []
        }
      ],
      "shipping_lines": [
        {
          "id": 501,
          "method_id": "flat_rate",
          "method_title": "Flat Rate",
          "total": "10.00"
        }
      ],
      "tax_lines": [
        {
          "id": 502,
          "rate_id": "5",
          "code": "US-CA-TAX-1",
          "title": "Tax",
          "total": "4.40",
          "compound": false
        },
        {
          "id": 503,
          "rate_id": "4",
          "code": "US-STANDARD-1",
          "title": "Standard",
          "total": "1.50",
          "compound": false
        }
      ],
      "fee_lines": [],
      "coupon_lines": [],
      "customer": {
        "id": 2,
        "created_at": "2014-11-19T18:34:19Z",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "username": "john.doe",
        "last_order_id": "645",
        "last_order_date": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
        "orders_count": 2,
        "total_spent": "19.00",
        "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=96",
        "billing_address": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "company": "",
          "address_1": "969 Market",
          "address_2": "",
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "state": "CA",
          "postcode": "94103",
          "country": "US",
          "email": "john.doe@example.com",
          "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
        },
        "shipping_address": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "company": "",
          "address_1": "969 Market",
          "address_2": "",
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "state": "CA",
          "postcode": "94103",
          "country": "US"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
Available Filters

Filter  Type    Description
status  string  Orders by status. eg: processing or cancelled
Update An Order
This API lets you make changes to an order.

HTTP Request

PUT /wc-api/v3/orders/<id>
data = {
    "order": {
        "status": "completed"
    }
}

print(wcapi.put("orders/645", data).json())
JSON response example:
{
  "order": {
    "id": 645,
    "order_number": 645,
    "created_at": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
    "completed_at": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
    "status": "completed",
    "currency": "USD",
    "total": "79.87",
    "subtotal": "63.97",
    "total_line_items_quantity": 3,
    "total_tax": "5.90",
    "total_shipping": "10.00",
    "cart_tax": "5.40",
    "shipping_tax": "0.50",
    "total_discount": "0.00",
    "shipping_methods": "Flat Rate",
    "payment_details": {
      "method_id": "bacs",
      "method_title": "Direct Bank Transfer",
      "paid": true
    },
    "billing_address": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "company": "",
      "address_1": "969 Market",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "CA",
      "postcode": "94103",
      "country": "US",
      "email": "john.doe@example.com",
      "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "company": "",
      "address_1": "969 Market",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "CA",
      "postcode": "94103",
      "country": "US"
    },
    "note": "",
    "customer_ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "customer_user_agent": "WordPress/4.1; http://example.com",
    "customer_id": 2,
    "view_order_url": "https://example.com/my-account/view-order/645",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "id": 504,
        "subtotal": "43.98",
        "subtotal_tax": "4.40",
        "total": "43.98",
        "total_tax": "4.40",
        "price": "21.99",
        "quantity": 2,
        "tax_class": "reduced-rate",
        "name": "Premium Quality",
        "product_id": 546,
        "sku": "",
        "meta": []
      },
      {
        "id": 505,
        "subtotal": "19.99",
        "subtotal_tax": "1.00",
        "total": "19.99",
        "total_tax": "1.00",
        "price": "19.99",
        "quantity": 1,
        "tax_class": null,
        "name": "Ship Your Idea",
        "product_id": 613,
        "sku": "",
        "meta": [
          {
            "key": "pa_color",
            "label": "Color",
            "value": "Black"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "shipping_lines": [
      {
        "id": 506,
        "method_id": "flat_rate",
        "method_title": "Flat Rate",
        "total": "10.00"
      }
    ],
    "tax_lines": [
      {
        "id": 507,
        "rate_id": "5",
        "code": "US-CA-TAX-1",
        "title": "Tax",
        "total": "4.40",
        "compound": false
      },
      {
        "id": 508,
        "rate_id": "4",
        "code": "US-STANDARD-1",
        "title": "Standard",
        "total": "1.50",
        "compound": false
      }
    ],
    "fee_lines": [],
    "coupon_lines": [],
    "customer": {
      "id": 2,
      "created_at": "2014-11-19T18:34:19Z",
      "email": "john.doe@example.com",
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": "",
      "username": "john.doe",
      "last_order_id": "645",
      "last_order_date": "2015-01-26T20:00:21Z",
      "orders_count": 2,
      "total_spent": "19.00",
      "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=96",
      "billing_address": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
      },
      "shipping_address": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "",
        "address_1": "969 Market",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "postcode": "94103",
        "country": "US"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm looking to then turn it into a transactional dataframe that would list sku, quantity and the completed at date.

Comment: Can you show your code for this please?

Comment: do you know how to turn that text into python objects?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that, you need:

- Convert your JSON string into a JSON object (using the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module);
- Create a function to filter the orders according to you criterion;
- run the filter function to extract matching orders

Example:

```
import json

json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
orders = json_obj["orders"]
completed = lambda order: order["status"] == "completed"
selected_orders = filter(completed, orders)
```